# HAProxy - Application Sessions between different applications JSESSIONID and PHPSESSID

Tags: php, session, tomcat, haproxy

If I use

```
cookie serverid insert indirect nocache
```

This creates a cookie like so...

```
SessionID: s1
SessionID: s2
So on...
```

The problem is PCI compliance flags this as a session and because it is not random it fails.

The next issue is we have multiple web technologies.  Tomcat and PHP.  So I can not simply do the following...

```
cookie JSESSIONID prefix nocache
```

or

```
cookie PHPSESSID prefix nocache
```

As both technologies run on the same backend servers.

Most sites are Tomcat which use JSESSIONID.  We only have 4 PHP sites that use PHPSESSID but I would prefer not to have to create new servers for those 4 sites.

So my question is...  Is there a way to look for JSESSIONID and PHPSESSID and use which ever one the backend server responds with?

Other suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring servers. ServerFault.com would be a better place for questions like this.